# Is it possible to build a DApp with Django and web3.js?

Tags: python, django, web3js, web3py

I am building a Dapp. The site infrastructure was built with Django, before I realised I want it to have something to do with crypto and blockchain.

We want it to be able to talk and communicate the ethereal blockchain. So we have to use a web3 package, either web3.js (javascript), or web3.py (python).

Unfortunately, web3.py is not as developed as web3.js, which is why all my endeavors to utilize Django for metamask integration have not been successful.

So I think I have no choice but to use javascript. But clearly I don’t want to abandon all the work done with Django…

So, is it possible to build a Dapp, with the overall UI and website infrastructure using Django, while the parts that are blockchain-related (say metamask initialisation), be built with javascript and locally-contained? Is this possible? Would there be hidden security risks?

Comment: Have you looked into using Ethereum's python implementations?
You can find the documentation here: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/programming-languages/python/

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility, you can use login initialization in web3.js on frontend side and other things with web3.py and Django.

You can see a python library [Django-web3-Auth](https://github.com/Bearle/django-web3-auth).
This will give you a hint for this.
Read the library code to understand this thing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30124694)